# How to show the complete legend in the plot window of Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to plot some of my results in Dymola, but when I plot a few curves in one graph, the legend can't show completely, is there any setup I could use to let the legend show completely?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select from various legend styles in the plot window setup.

In your case *Right* would be the choice.

[image: plot window setup]